# Bind events on body or document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Sometimes the users bind the events on `$('body')` and sometimes on `$(document)`

```
$(document).on('click', someAction);

$('body').on('click', someAction);
```

Is there some reason to prefer one to another?

Comment: See the link given by SpYk3HH, $(document) selector is faster

Answer (score 8):

For me, there is mainly one reason to  bind the events on `$(document)` and not to `$('body')`:

> no need to wait **domReady** (document is available before everything
>   else)

Answer (score 6):

Short answer most likely is, no, not really.

The reason someone is doing it should always be that he requires to catch an event globally in his markup. Since the `<body>` tag should follow as direct sibling to `<html>`, all events bubbling phase will end there.

```
<html>
    <body>
         <div>
         </div>
```

Every click event on `<div>` would bubble up to `<body>` as well as `<html>` (if not stopped manually). So for that usecase it should not make any difference.

Answer (score 2):

There is some difference in speed, not much else. Someone has already done the work though so I'll just point you the link.

### http://jsperf.com/jquery-body-vs-document-body-selector

However, in direct relation to your code there, there is one major difference. `$(document).on('click', someAction);` will affect anywhere on the document viewing area, whereas `$('body').on('click', someAction);` Might not affect as much area as body can have an independent height and width.

Comment: I don't think is related to my question because the difference is about `document.body` and `body` not `document` and `body`.

Comment: document is body, but with object properties. They are all basically the same thing, except that document gives you properties to manipulate that affect your entire page, where as body is treated like any other html element

Comment: So according you explanation `$('body')` should be faster than `$(document)` but to me it seems the contrary from your [reference](http://jsperf.com/jquery-body-vs-document-body-selector).

Comment: No, `technically`, body is an element OF Document, however, my point is, virtually anything you do to body/$("body"), you can do to document/document.body/$(document).children("body") and expect the same result, the difference in all being milliseconds of time for processing.